# Cordova app slows down Android multi-task UI and message center

Tags: android, performance, cordova, ionic-framework

I am currently developing a **Cordova** app targeting **Android**, using **Ionic**. I noticed that the android multi-task UI (if you tap the context button next to the home button on your phone) slows down heavily if the app is active. If I close the Cordova app, it's running fluently again. This happens to Cordova apps with and without the use of Ionic.

My app also uses the [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode), and if I start background mode with a sticky notification, it slows down the Android message center (But only if the sticky notification is visible). Though I think this issue might be related to Ionic, since another sample app I created without Ionic does not have this issue.

I profiled the app using Android Studio's Monitor, but it does not seem to use a lot of Memory (10MB) or CPU (0.8%) when running in background, so I don't understand where these performance drops come from.

Has anyone else had these kinds of performance issues and found a way to improve them? I tried **prod/release-mode** and **Crosswalk** already, both did not work (prod mode improved the app startup time though).

Here are my system configurations:

```
Node version: v6.10.0
Cordova CLI : 6.5.0
Ionic: 3.6.0 (ng) / 2.1.4 (app-scripts)
Android SDK: AP25
android-minSdkVersion: 16
Test Phone: HTC10
```

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour without background mode plugin?

Comment: the multitask slowdown appears without the background mode plugin aswell, the message center slowdown only appears with the background mode plugin AND Ionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mhm strange, I actually found a solution.. For some reason, using a **custom icon** for the background mode plugin sticky notification solved the problem with the message center...

The multitask UI seems to run smoother after I added a timer interval that actually **periodically updates the ui** (a little spinner that indicates an active connection within the app). For some reason, it seems like the multitask UI does not slow down if the GPU is always a little busy (a very tiny task) with the app...